# Is there a CTabCtrl in CPropertySheet?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

`CPropertySheet` looks like it has a `CTabCtrl` inside it. But when i checked the code of `CPropertySheet`, I saw there is no tab control instance. So, how does it manage the tab control?

Besides, i saw in `AddPage` and `RemovePage` function, it sends `PSM_ADDPAGE` and `PSM_REMOVEPAGE` message to itself but didn't handle those messages. Why is it doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property sheets aren't actually implemented in MFC - MFC is just a thin wrapper around the Win32 API that creates them. The tab control is created and managed internally by the property sheet API, and it doesn't expose that control to outside users. You aren't meant to interact with the tab directly. Instead you use the property sheet messages (or MFC wrapper functions) and it handles the tab control automatically.

Similarly, the `PSM_ADDPAGE` and `PSM_REMOVEPAGE` are handled internally by the property sheet's dialog procedure.